# Silex command fail

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, silex

I have this error when I try to run a console command with Silex.

```
PHP Error:  Class 'Testing\Command\TestingCommand' not found in /var/www/testCmd/app/console on line 9
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/testCmd/app/console:0
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "TestingCommand" from namespace "Testing\Command".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in /var/www/testCmd/app/console:9
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/testCmd/app/console on line 9
```

I have app/console.php and app/bootstrap.php files. The console is loading the bootstrap and in the console file I have some thing like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

set_time_limit(0);

$app = require_once __DIR__ . '/bootstrap.php';

$application = $app['console'];
$app['console']->add(new \Testing\Command\TestingCommand());
$application->run();
```

composer file

```
{
    "name": "testing/Command",
    "require": {
        "knplabs/console-service-provider": "^2.0",
        "silex/silex": "^2.0",
        "symfony/monolog-bridge": "^3.1",
        "doctrine/common": "^2.6",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

The command is located in src/Command/TestingCommand.php

I am super new to Silex and I don't know what can cause the issue. Thank you

Comment: Where this command class is located? Add content of composer.json in question.

Comment: I updated the question with composer file info. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autoloader can't load command class. According to autoload section of composer.json and class name file with this class should be located in `src/Testing/Command/TestingCommand.php`. So you can move this file in this location or set another search directory in `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Testing\\Command\\": "src/Command/"
        "\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

after changing composer.json run `composer dump-autoload`

https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: I run the dump-autoload and I have this -> `A non-empty PSR-4 prefix must end with a namespace separator` . btw: I think there is a "," after the first line inside psr-4.